# How to replace the value of a column base on the condition of another 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

if the value in the column 'active' is equal to 0, or if the value in 'category' is equal to NaN, then the value in that specific row in 'position' should = 0.

Before;

```
active position category
1       1      NaN
1       2      NaN
1       1        a
0       1        a
0       1        a
1       2        a
1       1        b
0       1        b
1       2        b
```

after:

```
active position category
1       0      NaN
1       0      NaN
1       1        a
0       0        a
0       0        a
1       2        a
1       1        b
0       0        b
1       2        b
```

Comment: this is an example of cumulative sum. the position value will not add up when a new category starts

Comment: What do you mean? 0 OR null? Pick one...

Comment: can you edit your post to include text of the data rather than an image?  And can you also include what you think the output should look like.

Comment: I just made the changes to the dataframe. Someone helped me edited it, but the data was wrong.

Comment: and I want the position to be like this- 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, IIUC. Set all rows fulfilling your condition to 0:

```
In [355]: df.loc[(df.active == 0) | (df.category.isnull()), 'position'] = 0; df
Out[355]: 
   active  position category
0       1         0      NaN
1       1         0      NaN
2       1         1        a
3       0         0        a
4       0         0        a
5       1         2        a
6       1         1        b
7       0         0        b
8       1         2        b
```

All other rows remain unchanged.